# GPU memeory is not released even after a process has finished running inside tmux

Tags: ubuntu, gpu, nvidia, tmux

I used `tmux new-session` to create a tmux process and then run my PyTorch code on GPU using `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 CUBLAS_WORKSPACE_CONFIG=:16:8 python main.py`. After using `nvidia-smi` to check the GPUs' status, I noticed that some of the GPUs memories are still allocated to the tmux processes, despite the fact that they were finished running. If I use `ctrl+c` to terminate a tmux process, the memory gets freed up. If I kill the tmux processes, the memory releases too. I don't get what the issue is. Is there a way to guarantee that when a tmux process is finished, the GPU memory is fully released again?

Answer (score 0):

This problem probably is not because of tmux since I noticed the same effect when I ran models by jupyter without using tmux before including lines for clearing memory cache. Try putting some codes for clearing memory cache at the end of your codes like this:

```
# Clear the memory
del model, trainX, trainY  # or any other heavy parameters you've defined
torch.cuda.empty_cache()  # for pytorch only
gc.collect()
```

For tensorflow users, you can include `tf.keras.backend.clear_session()` instead of `torch.cuda.empty_cache()`.